# How can I split a value with a space from into two columns in SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, split

Given a table like the following:

| Firstname | Lastname | Fullname |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Null | Null | Elen Morales |
| Null | Null | Sasha Karl Wickens |

In the future I would like the column "Fullname" to no longer exist, the values should be split into "Firstname" and "Lastname". The possibility to separate the two values would be the last space each because some names have two First Names which both should be transfered to "Firstname".

I've been trying for a while now, but I can't come up with a expression.

Do you have any ideas on how I can solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
UPDATE
    Sometable
SET
    Firstname = REGEXP_REPLACE(' [^ ]*$', '', Fullname),
    Lastname = REGEXP_REPLACE('.* ', '', Fullname)
```

Be very careful when pasting code above not to mess up the spaces in regexps

Comment: Thank you, I don't know how I didn't think of it. My thinking was far too complicated...

Answer (score 0):

You could `REGEXP_REPLACE` here:

```sql
SELECT
    REGEXP_REPLACE(Fullname, '^(.*) \S+$', '\1') AS Firstname,
    REGEXP_REPLACE(Fullname, '^.* (\S+)$', '\1') AS Lastname,
    Fullname
FROM yourTable;
```

If you want to actually update your table, then use:

```sql
UPDATE yourTable
SET
    Firstname = REGEXP_REPLACE(Fullname, '^(.*) \S+$', '\1'),
    Lastname  = REGEXP_REPLACE(Fullname, '^.* (\S+)$', '\1');
```